# Change Image based on redirect_to URL

Tags: javascript

I just removed the whole question so I can start from scratch.

```js
var redirectURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
if (redirectURL.includes("men")) {
  alert('Mens');
  $('#imageDiv').css("background", "url('https://mydomainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/STORE2.png')");  
} 
else if (redirectURL.includes("women")) {
  alert('Womens');  
  $('#imageDiv').css("background", "url('https://mydomainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/STORE.png')");     
}
```

```css
#imageDiv{
  background: url(https://mydomainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/compressed-Recovered.png);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageDiv"></div>
```

This is not working as desired.  The alerts show as they should but the image is not changing.  THis is loading at the bottom of my page.

Answer:

```
var redirectURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
if (redirectURL.includes("men")) {
  const imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
  imageDiv.dataset.style = "men";
} 
else if (redirectURL.includes("women")) {
  const imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
  imageDiv.dataset.style = "women";
   
}
```

Comment: is men and women include as a path in the url?

Comment: I got it sorted out.  Thank you for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

I would consider avoiding parsing the path unless you must. Does something like below work as expected?

```
`if (window.location.pathname.includes('women')) {
    image.src = 'women-url';
} else {
    image.src = 'men-url';
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your problem, the following solution occurs to me

in html

```html
<div id='banner'>...<div/>
```

in css

```css
#banner[data-selection='womans'] {
  background: url(...)
}

#banner[data-selection='mans'] {
  background: url(...)
}
```

in javascript

```js
const ctrlText = window.location.pathname.includes('womens');
const banner = document.getElementById('banner');
if (ctrlText) {
  banner.dataset.selection = ctrlText.toLowerCase();
} else {
  banner.dataset.selection = 'mens';
}
```

although personally and whenever you can, it would be better if the default `div` or `img` are manipulated in the layout from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes to store the "style" that you want to refer to. Then use CSS selectors to target the data attribute. Also you would want to start with searching for WOMEN, because WOMEN includes the word MEN.

So searching for Men if the URL contains Women it would still return true.

```js
const imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
imageDiv.dataset.style = (window.location.pathname.includes('womens')) ? "womens" : "mens"
```

```css
#imageDiv{height:300px;}

#imageDiv[data-style='womens'] {
  background: url('https://fakeimg.pl/600x400?text=WOMEN')
}

#imageDiv[data-style='mens'] {
  background: url('https://fakeimg.pl/600x400?text=MEN')
}
```

```html
<div id='imageDiv'><div/>
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work on my site.  Working in JS fiddle but some reason not in wordpress.

Comment: @DiamondD is there any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors.  Could it be cache?

Comment: There are so many reasons why its not working in your website. Cache is a great place to start.

Comment: I got it to work by combining some answers.  I will post in my question